# Distance from Chicago to New York

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

An airplane flies $520$ miles from Chicago to Virginia. Then it turns $45$ degrees to  face New York and flies $630$ miles to New York. What is the distance from Chicago to New York?

Given the $45$ degrees to start with I've attempted to get the answer of $713$ miles, which I looked up, but when I divide $520/ cos(45)$, I get $735$ on my calculator. Is there inaccuracy in this problem, or am I doing a portion of
it incorrectly?

Comment: there is a law of Cosines for the surface of a sphere; actually, there are two laws of Cosines. It is necessary to include the radius of the sphere (the earth) as part of the Law. Meanwhile, it is consistent that the true distance is smaller than what would be correct in a flat plane. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines

Comment: So technically  this measurement should be a little off because the earth is not flat.

Comment: Why would it be $520/\cos(45)$? That seems to mean the distance is independent of the second leg...

Comment: Yes, but I do not know where you are getting your figures. Virginia is not a city, it is a state, with many cities

Comment: I suppose they meant the state.

Comment: I looked up this information of the distance from NY to Virginia is actually around 414 miles.So the numbers given are off.

Comment: Yes, the numbers are made up - it is an exercise, but not meant to be a real representation of the distances involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't possibly be $520/\cos(45^{\circ}),$ because that is completely independent of the second leg of the journey.

You seem to have assumed that the triangle formed by Chicago, Virginia, New York is a right triangle. That is not assumed in the question.

The correct answer (assuming the world is flat) is to use the law of cosines:

$$d^2=520^2+630^2-2\cdot 520\cdot 630\cdot\cos(135^{\circ})$$

Note: A turn of $45^{\circ}$ gives a triangle with an angle of $135^{\circ}$.

Solve for $d$. You get a much larger value this way - the triangle is obtuse, so the distance is greater than $520$ and $630$.

Comment: You used the law of cosines right?

Comment: @user242559 $d^2=.... $ is the Law of Cosines